# How does OCaml represent calls to the allocator in generated assembly?

Tags: ocaml

According to [Real World OCaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/compiler-backend.html), compiled OCaml code is garbage collected on certain invocations of the allocator in the C runtime. What do these allocation calls look like in the generated assembly of an OCaml program?

Answer (score 4):

(Note: I assume that by the phrase "OCaml code is garbage collected" you don't mean that the code itself is garbage collected. You're just discussing how garbage collection happens while OCaml code is running.)

Here's a small function that allocates space:

```
let f x =
    x :: []
```

Here is the generated code (with some unnecessary pseudo-ops removed):

```
        .globl      _camlM__f_80
_camlM__f_80:
        subq        $8, %rsp
L100:
        movq        %rax, %rbx
L101:
        subq        $24, %r15
        cmpq        8(%r14), %r15
        jb  L102
        leaq        8(%r15), %rax
        movq        $2048, -8(%rax)
        movq        %rbx, (%rax)
        movq        $1, 8(%rax)
        addq        $8, %rsp
        ret
L102:
        call        _caml_call_gc2
L103:
        jmp L101
```

As you can see, the code allocates memory just by subtracting the desired size (24 bytes) from the memory boundary in r15. (This is inspired by [Cheney's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheney%27s_algorithm).) The code then compares the new memory boundary with the end of available memory. If it's past the end, the code jumps to call `_caml_call_gc2` to do a GC, then jumps back to try again.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I meant how garbage collection happens while OCaml code is running. I think I understand now.  Is the value x being passed in on register %rbx? And what is the `addq        $8, %rsp` instruction doing?

Comment: Nothing is passed in `%rbx`. It gets set to `%rax` right away. There is a local stack frame of size 8  created by `subq $8, %rsp`. The `addq $8, %rsp` at the end deallocates the stack frame before returning.